# Converting data to JSON in same format as CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have the following code which prints the object as CSV:

```
title = ['Username', 'Name', 'Job']
for x in title:
    print(x, end =",")

for d in data:
    line = d.get_username() + "," + d.get_name() + "," + d.get_role()
    print(line)
```

I get:

```
Username,Name,Job
rob,robert,developer
danny21,danny,developer
```

I want to print the same data as JSON in order to get:

```
[ 
   { 
      "Username":"rob",
      "Name":"robert",
      "Job":"developer"
   },
   { 
      "Username":"danny21",
      "Name":"danny",
      "Job":"developer"
   }
]
```

From previous topics I learn that we can use `json.dumps` but I'm not sure if it helps in this case.
What is the proper way to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert CSV to JSON (in specific format) using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642673/convert-csv-to-json-in-specific-format-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
l = []
for d in data:
    user_dictionary = {}
    user_dictionary[title[0]] = d.get_username()
    user_dictionary[title[1]] = d.get_name()
    user_dictionary[title[2]] = d.get_role()
    l.append(user_dictionary)
```

to get a json like file.

You can also avoid appending and do:

```
def get_user_data(user):
    user_dictionary = {}
    user_dictionary[title[0]] = d.get_username()
    user_dictionary[title[1]] = d.get_name()
    user_dictionary[title[2]] = d.get_role()
    return user_dictionary

l = list(map(get_user_data, data))
```

You can use json.dump to dump l in a file

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(l, outfile)
```